# How to reuse variables from the base class to the derived class

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I am working on a project to show statistics for a generic vehicle, then for a car and a truck.
All of the objects have a Manufacturer and Model Year, but the Car has a number of doors, and the truck has a towing capacity.

I have my vehicle class and class constructors all working properly in the code.

Now I want to call the same method of data storage from the base class Vehicle, and use it for the Car Class.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
  private:
    string manu;
    int year;

  public:
    // Default constructor
    Vehicle() {
        manu = "";
        year = 0;
    }

    // Constructor
    Vehicle(string autoManu, int autoYear) {
        manu = autoManu;
        year = autoYear;
    }

    // Accessors
    string getManu() const { return manu; }

    int getModel() const { return year; }

    void storeInfo(string autoManu, int autoYear);
    void displayInfo();
};
```

This is my **Vehicle.h** file ^

```
#include "Vehicle.h"

void Vehicle::storeInfo(string autoManu, int autoYear) {
    manu = autoManu;

    year = autoYear;
}
void Vehicle::displayInfo() {
    cout << "Manufacturer- " << manu << endl;
    cout << "Make Year- " << year << endl;
}
```

This is my Vehicle.cpp file ^

These both work perfectly, now I want to use the same kind of displayInfo for the Car class.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// The Car class represents a car.
class Car : public Vehicle {
  private:
    int doors;

  public:
    // Default constructor
    Car() : Vehicle() { doors = 0; }

    // Constructor #2
    Car(string carManu, int carYear, int carDoors) : Vehicle(carManu, carYear) {
        doors = carDoors;
    }

    // Accessor for doors attribute
    int getDoors() { return doors; }

    void storeInfo(string autoManu, int autoYear, int carDoors);
    void displayInfo();
};
```

This is my **Car.h** file ^

```
#include "Car.h"

void Car::storeInfo(string autoManu, int autoYear, int carDoors) {
    manu = autoManu;

    year = autoYear;

    doors = carDoors;
}

void Car::displayInfo() {
    cout << "Manufacturer- " << manu << endl;
    cout << "Make Year- " << year << endl;
    cout << "Doors on the Car" << doors << endl;
}
```

This is the **Car.cpp** file.
The issue I am encountering is that the menu and year variables, the variables defined in the base class, are saying "Vehicle::manu is inaccessible"

What would be causing this, and what is the fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Call `Vechicle::displayInfo();` in `Car::displayInfo()` . And similarly with `storeInfo`. You already know how to delegate to base class constructor - now learn to delegate to base class' member function.

Comment: You could make your variables `protected` so the derived classes can access them.